# How to Raise Events in Application level XAML styles

Tags: .net, windows, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating Universal app for Windows and Windows Phone.
Hence I declared different Styles.xaml files for both types of project.

But styles also contains some click events in it which are not getting fired How can I fore those click events.

**AppliationStyle.xaml** is here

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="albumDataTemplate">
        <Border CornerRadius="30" Background="LightGreen" Padding="10" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="White" Height="460" BorderThickness="2" Width="250">
            <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Vertical" >
                <Image Source="{Binding Url}"  Margin="5" Height="220"  Width="200"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="25" Foreground="Purple"  />
                <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" 
                                   Foreground="White" >                                
                                <Run Text="Artist :" />
                                <Run Text="{Binding ArtistName}" Foreground="Red" />
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" 
                                   Foreground="Purple" >
                                <Run Text="Price :  $" />
                                <Run Text="{Binding Price}" Foreground="Red" />
                </TextBlock>
                <Image Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Rating}"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Add Album To Cart" Tag="{Binding Id}" Click="OnAddToCart"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0 20 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="60" Width="60" Padding="0">
                    <Image Source="Images/cart/shoppingcart_add.png" />
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I am using this above styles in a user control which is common to both Win 8.1 and Win phone 8.1 projects. **AlbumView.xaml**

```
<Grid>
        <GridView ItemsPanel="{StaticResource albumItemPanelTemplate}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource albumDataTemplate}" 
                  SelectionMode="Single" x:Name="albumListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectedAlbum" >

        </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

I am having definition of those CLick handler in **AlbumView.xaml.cs** like this

```
private async void OnAddToCart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

So what is the alternative way to bind those event with the code exists in code behind file. I got some way of writing eventsetter , but cant make it fit into this scenario.

Comment: You can bind an `ICommand` to the `Click` event. MVVM Light got a helper for that. You can then store the command in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You probably had to define the click method (OnAddToChart) in ApplicationStyle.xaml.cs in order for your project to compile... and that is the methood called when you click on that button, not the one on the AlbumView page.

I had the same issue as I had a item template defined in App.xaml and was trying to get the button Click event on another page.

I too want to know how to deal with this situation... How do I get a Click event from a  template defined globally?

My solution was to define the template locally for every list that I needed the event... lots of duplicated item template code...

in you case it would be something like this

```
<GridView ItemsPanel="{StaticResource albumItemPanelTemplate}" 
                  SelectionMode="Single" x:Name="albumListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectedAlbum" >
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="albumDataTemplate">
        <Border CornerRadius="30" Background="LightGreen" Padding="10" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="White" Height="460" BorderThickness="2" Width="250">
            <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Vertical" >
                <Image Source="{Binding Url}"  Margin="5" Height="220"  Width="200"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="25" Foreground="Purple"  />
                <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" 
                                   Foreground="White" >                                
                                <Run Text="Artist :" />
                                <Run Text="{Binding ArtistName}" Foreground="Red" />
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" 
                                   Foreground="Purple" >
                                <Run Text="Price :  $" />
                                <Run Text="{Binding Price}" Foreground="Red" />
                </TextBlock>
                <Image Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Rating}"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Add Album To Cart" Tag="{Binding Id}" Click="OnAddToCart"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0 20 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="60" Width="60" Padding="0">
                    <Image Source="Images/cart/shoppingcart_add.png" />
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>

        </GridView>
```